# Add multiple forms in spring boot java.util.ConcurrentModificationException\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

hi guys i have a problem i have two entities product and category i want to add a category and multiple product in the same form like that in this capture

[image]

this is my entity Category

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Category {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idcategory;
    
    private String nom;
    
    @JsonManagedReference("category")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<Product> products= new ArrayList<>();
    
     public void add(Product item) {

            if (item != null) {
                if (products == null) {
                    products= new ArrayList<>();
                }

                products.add(item);
                item.setCategory(this);
            }
        }

}
```

and this is entity Product

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Product {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idproduct;
    
    private String nom;
    
    private Integer prix;
    
    @JsonBackReference("category")
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoryproduct", referencedColumnName = "idcategory")
    
    private Category category;

}
```

and this is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addcategory(@RequestBody Category c) throws IOException {
 
        List<Product> products = c.getProducts();
        products.forEach(item -> c.add(item)
                                
                );  
            
            categorieRepository.save(c);
                
        }
```

when i try to post a category and multiple product it shows this problem

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException\\r\\n\\tat java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1513)\\r\\n\\tat com.example.users.controller.CategoryController.addcategory(CategoryController.java:46)\\r\\n\\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

i want to know whats wrong with my code and how to fix that guys

Comment: What is the purpose/what *does* `forEach` loop (in controller)? (Delete/comment (forEach) & re-try!;)

Comment: bro i fix that thanks anyway, i changed List to Set and it works

Comment: List<Product> products = c.getProducts();
        products.forEach(item -> c.add(item)
                                
                );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix that i changed List to Set and i changed @Data annotation to @getter and @setter cuz i faced a new error (java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode) and it works now

Answer (score 0):

You just need to save c, as it already contains everything to save. Ain't need no loop whatsoever.
ConcurrentModificationException is when you alter entity while in for-loop.
This question here would have helped you:

[Hibernate throwing a ConcurrentModificationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534424/hibernate-throwing-a-concurrentmodificationexception)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Product> products = c.getProducts();
products.forEach(item -> c.add(item));
```

The problem is here. You are trying to iterate over the list and trying to add items to the same list. It is not possible. You can add a temporary list to add the items.