# What is the difference between Hashtable and HashMap if both throws ConcurrentModificationException in following code snippet?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashtable

In following code snippet, I tried with both `Hashtable` which is so called as thread safe and `HashMap`. But in both the cases I am getting `ConcurrentModificationExceptionn`. If this is so, then what is the advantages of `HashTable` over `HashMap` in case of thread safety

```
public class multiThreadedEnv {
    static Map<Integer, String> map = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
    //static Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    static{
        map.put(1, "One");
        map.put(2, "Two");
        map.put(3, "Three");
        map.put(4, "Four");
        map.put(5, "Five");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                Iterator itr= map.entrySet().iterator();
                while(itr.hasNext()){
                    Entry<String,String> entry=(Entry<String, String>) itr.next();
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" , "+entry.getValue());
                    itr.remove();
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t2= new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                Iterator itr= map.entrySet().iterator();
                while(itr.hasNext()) {
                    Entry<String,String> entry=(Entry<String, String>) itr.next();
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" , "+entry.getValue());
                    itr.remove();
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: The whole reason `Hashtable` was essentially deprecated was that it made you _think_ you had thread-safety when you didn't really.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug ConcurrentModificationException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840165/how-to-debug-concurrentmodificationexception)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Be careful when you say `Hashtable` and "deprecated" in the same sentence when I'm within earshot. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) is synchronized, preventing two threads from accessing it at the same time.

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the `Map` interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, `Hashtable` is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `HashMap` in place of `Hashtable`. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use `ConcurrentHashMap` in place of `Hashtable`.

[`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is not synchronized.

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings; merely changing the value associated with a key that an instance already contains is not a structural modification.)

Synchronizing does not prevent `ConcurrentModificationException`, because **they both say**:

> The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are *fail-fast*: if the [Hashtable/map] is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own `remove` method, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Note that a single thread can cause `ConcurrentModificationException` by updating the Hashtable/HashMap directly while also iterating it. It doesn't require multi-threading to violate this rule.

[`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) says:

> Iterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do *not* throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time.

So, `HashMap` is useful for single-threaded access.
`Hashtable` is useful for multi-threaded access, as long as they don't need to iterate the map.
`ConcurrentHashMap` allows updates and iteration by multiple threads.